# How can I input a non-number to print something else instead of having an error using while loops?

Tags: python, math, while-loop

I have to calculate factorials of given numbers, which have inputs of 4, 9, and abc123.
This is my coding so far but for abc123 is where the error is. How can I edit this so that it does not show an error but printing something else?

```
for i in range(0,2):
  num = int(input('Enter a number: '))
  factorial = 1
  if num < 0:
    print('Sorry! Factorials cannot be negative numbers.')
  else:
    for i in range(1, num + 1):
      factorial = factorial*i
    print(num, '!=', factorial)
```

Comment: What do you expect as the output for the input "abc123" ? You get an error because you convert your input to int, and "abc123" cannot be converted to int. I think you want to catch the ValueError on the input line and to ask the user to enter a number - it depends of course in the expected behaviour for this input.

Comment: Please look up and follow one of the many tutorials available online on [exception handling](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+exception+handling). [Asking on Stack Overflow is not a substitute for doing your own research.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `try except` to handle non-integers as:

```
for i in range(0,3):
    try:
      num = int(input('Enter a number: '))
      factorial = 1
      if num < 0:
        print('Sorry! Factorials cannot be negative numbers.')
      else:
        for i in range(1, num + 1):
          factorial = factorial*i
        print(num, '!=', factorial)
    except Exception as ex:
        print("Invalid input. Try again")
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your call to `int` in a `try/except` block

```py
try:
    foo = int(input())
except Exception:
    print("exception occurred")
```

this can be made much more advanced with some extra feedback about the error and also arguably better by capturing only the minimum Exception expected

```py
while True:
    _value = input("Enter a number: ")
    try:
        value = int(_value)
    except ValueError:
        print("invalid input!: {}".format(_value)
        continue  # jump to top of loop
```

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic way to handle errors in Python is with `try: ... except: ...` blocks:

```
for i in range(0,2):
  inp = input('Enter a number: '))
  try:
    num = int(inp)
  except ValueError:
    print('>{}< is not a valid number'.format(num))
    continue
  factorial = 1
  if num < 0:
    print('Sorry! Factorials cannot be negative numbers.')
  else:
    for i in range(1, num + 1):
      factorial = factorial*i
    print(num, '!=', factorial)
```

Please note that the exception clause should only catch the exception you want to handle. Avoid catch all exception blocks, because they can silently *swallow* various errors and make some problems harder to diagnose...